# Statements outside of the Kleene Hierarchy?

Tags: lo.logic

I take a list of $2*m$ natural numbers {$n_k$}. I encode them in some way together to a single bit sequence. Now I feed this bit sequence to a Turing machine $T$. Call the statement "For all $n_1$, there exists an $n_2$ so that for all $n_3$, there exists an $n_4$... so that for all $n_{2*m-1}$, there exists an $n_{2*m}$ so that the Turing machine $T$ halts." statement $S_m$.

Now: Can statements of the form "There exists a $m$ so that statement $S_m$ is true" be, in general, formalized within the general notation for number-theoretic statements; does it lie in the Kleene Hierarchy?

Comment: I believe that you are essentially just asking about Post's theorem. It isn't clear to me if the machine $T$ is supposed to be fixed, or if it is a parameter somehow. It is also not clear to me whether this is a research-level question; once the details are clarified Post's theorem will almost certainly give an immediate answer. 

Answer (score 6):

The answer is no.

Consider first the following version of the question. Regarding your Turing machine $T$ as a parameter, let $\varphi_{T,m}$ be the statement: $$\forall n_1\exists n_2\forall n_3\cdots\exists n_{2m}\ \  T\ \text{ accepts }\ \langle n_1,n_2,\ldots,n_{2m}\rangle.$$

The question is whether $\varphi_{T,m}$ is an assertion about $T$ and $m$ that exists in the Kleene hierarchy. In other words, does the set $S=\{(T,m)\mid \varphi_{T,m}\}$ have arithmetic complexity?

The answer to this version of the question is no. This set has [hyperarithmetic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperarithmetical_theory) complexity, which is on top of the Kleene arithmetic hierarchy. The reason is that it is essentially a truth predicate for arithmetic truth. For any $\Sigma_{2m}$ sentence $\forall n_1\cdots\exists n_{2m}A(\vec n)$, where $A$ is $\Delta_0$, let $T$ be a Turing machine accepting the satisfying instances of $A$, and thus $\theta$ is true exactly when $\varphi_{T,m}$. It follows that one can compute all the iterated jumps $0^{(n)}$ from an oracle for $S$, and thus it has higher complexity than $\Sigma_n$ for any particular $n$. Meanwhile, the set $S$ is computable from the omega jump $0^{(\omega)}=\oplus_n 0^{(n)}=\{\langle n,x\rangle\mid x\in 0^{(n)}\}$, since we can decide $\Sigma_n$ truth uniformly from $0^{(n)}$. Thus, the set $S$ is Turing equivalent to $0^{(\omega)}$. This oracle is Turing equivalent to the set $\{{}^\ulcorner\varphi^\urcorner \mid \mathbb{N}\models\varphi\}$, as $\varphi$ ranges over the arithmetic assertions. This set is known as TA, for ``true arithmetic''.

The succinct way to say it is:  arithmetic truth is not arithmetic.

Now let's turn to your actual question, which is about the assertion $\exists m\ \varphi_{T,m}$, where you have quantified over $m$. Thus, your question is inquiring about the complexity of the set $\{T\mid \exists m\ \varphi_{T,m}\}$. The argument above gives the hyperarithmetic iterated jump $0^{(\omega+1)}$ as an upper bound on the complexity of this, since we can compute arithmetic truth from $0^{(\omega)}$, and you've added one more quantifier on top of this. Conversely, let's prove that the statement is not arithmetic. For any arithmetic sentence $\theta=\forall n_1\exists n_2\cdot \exists n_{2k}\psi(\vec n)$, where $\psi$ is $\Delta_0$, let $T$ be a Turing machine that accepts $\vec x$ just in case $\vec x$ has length $2k$ and $\psi(\vec x)$ holds. Thus, $\varphi_{T,m}$ holds if and only if $m=k$ and $\theta$ holds. Thus, your statement $\exists m\ \varphi_{T,m}$ holds if and only if $\theta$ holds. Thus, we have reduced TA to your set, and so your set is strictly in the hyperarithmetic hierarchy. So the answer is no.